# python 3.3 Beautifulsoup text between 2 sets of classes

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
.....
<div class="day"><div class="content">Idag<span id='updatedby'>, by <b>Karl</b> (100)     </span></div></div>

<div class="link"><a href="out.php?id=XXXXXX" target="_blank"><img src="img/ikon-   Hemsida.gif" class="type" alt="Hemsida" /><div class="text"> Sample text1 </div></a><br />   <div class="sbar"><img src="img/comment.gif" class="comment" alt="Kommentarer" /> <a    href="?p=komment&id=xxxxx">18 comments</a></div></div>

<div class="link"><a href="out.php?id=XXXXXX" target="_blank"><img src="img/ikon-Hemsida.gif" class="type" alt="Hemsida" /><div class="text"> Sample text2 </div></a><br /> <div class="sbar"><img src="img/comment.gif" class="comment" alt="Kommentarer" /> <a href="?p=komment&id=xxxxx">18 comments</a></div></div>

<div class="link"><a href="out.php?id=XXXXXX" target="_blank"><img src="img/ikon-Hemsida.gif" class="type" alt="Hemsida" /><div class="text"> Sample text3 </div></a><br />  <div class="sbar"><img src="img/comment.gif" class="comment" alt="Kommentarer" /> <a   href="?p=komment&id=xxxxx">18 comments</a></div></div>

<div class="day"><div class="content">2014-01-14<span id='updatedby'>, by<b>Person</b>  (50)</span></div></div>

""""**DO NOT PRINT THIS**""""
<div class="link"><a href="out.php?id=XXXXXX" target="_blank"><img src="img/ikon-Hemsida.gif" class="type" alt="Hemsida" /><div class="text"> Sample text4 </div></a><br /> <div class="sbar"><img src="img/comment.gif" class="comment" alt="Kommentarer" /> <a href="?p=komment&id=xxxxx">18 comments</a></div></div> 
""""**DO NOT PRINT THIS**""""
....
```

From that html i want to extract everything inbetween the first div with class="day" to the next div with class="day"

The output should be:

```
<div class="link"><a href="out.php?id=XXXXXX" target="_blank"><img src="img/ikon- Hemsida.gif" class="type" alt="Hemsida" /><div class="text"> Sample text1 </div></a><br /><div class="sbar"><img src="img/comment.gif" class="comment" alt="Kommentarer" /> <a href="?p=komment&id=xxxxx">18 comments</a></div></div>

<div class="link"><a href="out.php?id=XXXXXX" target="_blank"><img src="img/ikon-Hemsida.gif" class="type" alt="Hemsida" /><div class="text"> Sample text2 </div></a><br /><div class="sbar"><img src="img/comment.gif" class="comment" alt="Kommentarer" /> <a href="?p=komment&id=xxxxx">18 comments</a></div></div>

<div class="link"><a href="out.php?id=XXXXXX" target="_blank"><img src="img/ikon-Hemsida.gif" class="type" alt="Hemsida" /><div class="text"> Sample text3 </div></a><br /><div class="sbar"><img src="img/comment.gif" class="comment" alt="Kommentarer" /> <a href="?p=komment&id=xxxxx">18 comments</a></div></div>
```

My current code looks like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
soup = BeautifulSoup(open('text.html'))
contain = []
contain = soup.find_all('div',{'class':'day'})
del contain[2::]
print (contain)
```

And with this code the output i  get is:

```
[<div class="day"><div class="content">Idag<span id="updatedby">, by<b>Karl</b> (100)</span></div></div>, <div class="day"><div class="content">2014-01-14<span id="updatedby">, by <b>Person</b> (50)</span></div></div>]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = '''
<div class="day"><div class="content">Idag<span id='updatedby'>, by <b>Karl</b> (100)     </span></div></div>
<div class="link"><a href="out.php?id=XXXXXX" target="_blank"><img src="img/ikon-   Hemsida.gif" class="type" alt="Hemsida" /><div class="text"> Sample text1 </div></a><br />   <div class="sbar"><img src="img/comment.gif" class="comment" alt="Kommentarer" /> <a    href="?p=komment&id=xxxxx">18 comments</a></div></div>
<div class="link"><a href="out.php?id=XXXXXX" target="_blank"><img src="img/ikon-Hemsida.gif" class="type" alt="Hemsida" /><div class="text"> Sample text2 </div></a><br /> <div class="sbar"><img src="img/comment.gif" class="comment" alt="Kommentarer" /> <a href="?p=komment&id=xxxxx">18 comments</a></div></div>
<div class="link"><a href="out.php?id=XXXXXX" target="_blank"><img src="img/ikon-Hemsida.gif" class="type" alt="Hemsida" /><div class="text"> Sample text3 </div></a><br />  <div class="sbar"><img src="img/comment.gif" class="comment" alt="Kommentarer" /> <a   href="?p=komment&id=xxxxx">18 comments</a></div></div>
<div class="day"><div class="content">2014-01-14<span id='updatedby'>, by<b>Person</b>  (50)</span></div></div>
<div class="link"><a href="out.php?id=XXXXXX" target="_blank"><img src="img/ikon-Hemsida.gif" class="type" alt="Hemsida" /><div class="text"> Sample text4 </div></a><br /> <div class="sbar"><img src="img/comment.gif" class="comment" alt="Kommentarer" /> <a href="?p=komment&id=xxxxx">18 comments</a></div></div> 
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

result = []
tag = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'day'})[0]
while True:
    tag = tag.next_sibling
    if hasattr(tag, 'class') and 'day' in tag['class']:
        break
    result.append(tag)
for e in result:
    print(e)
```

Result:

```
<div class="link"><a href="out.php?id=XXXXXX" target="_blank"><img alt="Hemsida" class="type" src="img/ikon-   Hemsida.gif"/><div class="text"> Sample text1 </div></a><br/> <div class="sbar"><img alt="Kommentarer" class="comment" src="img/comment.gif"/> <a href="?p=komment&amp;id=xxxxx">18 comments</a></div></div>


<div class="link"><a href="out.php?id=XXXXXX" target="_blank"><img alt="Hemsida" class="type" src="img/ikon-Hemsida.gif"/><div class="text"> Sample text2 </div></a><br/> <div class="sbar"><img alt="Kommentarer" class="comment" src="img/comment.gif"/> <a href="?p=komment&amp;id=xxxxx">18 comments</a></div></div>


<div class="link"><a href="out.php?id=XXXXXX" target="_blank"><img alt="Hemsida" class="type" src="img/ikon-Hemsida.gif"/><div class="text"> Sample text3 </div></a><br/> <div class="sbar"><img alt="Kommentarer" class="comment" src="img/comment.gif"/> <a href="?p=komment&amp;id=xxxxx">18 comments</a></div></div>
```

This code assumes that you'll be dealing with a bunch of sibling nodes (no nesting). It starts at the first `class="day"` div and then steps through siblings and appends them to the result list until it hits the next `class="day"` div, at which point it `break`s out.

Comment: @Someone Glad I could help. If this solved your problem, consider "accepting" this answer by clicking on the checkmark below the upvote/downvote buttons.